# Creating Custom wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: custom-post-types

I have been working for many days on this. I want to assigned category to author. I have googled, found some tips and plugins but doesn't work with Wordpress 3.1. I just come up with my own idea.

I as admin will create a category for an author than define or put category slug name in their respective profile meta field.

I am using a Custom Post type name 'networks and taxonomy = blogs

Now I am trying to include only the profile meta field  value (I said above) in the wp dropdown categories as default and hide it in my custom posting form.

The cat ID and Name are correct when I echo it but it does not include in the drop list. Can anyone help me?

```
<?php
global $current_user;

get_currentuserinfo();

$authorcategory = get_the_author_meta('authorcategory', $current_user->ID);
$myterm = get_term_by( 'slug', $authorcategory, 'blogs');

if ( is_term( $authorcategory, 'blogs' && $authorcategory == $myterm ) ) {
    $my_cat_id = get_cat_id($authorcategory);
    $my_cat_name = get_cat_name($my_cat_id);
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'show_last_update' => 0,
        'style' => 'list',
        'show_count' => 0,
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'include' => $my_cat_name,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'title_li' => __( 'Categories' ),
        'show_option_none' => __('No categories'),
        'number' => NULL,
        'taxonomy' => 'blogs'
    );
    wp_dropdown_categories($args); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: `<?php global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$authorcategory = get_the_author_meta('authorcategory', $current_user->ID);
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'texonomy' ) );
if( is_term( $authorcategory, 'blogs', 'post_type=networks' && $term->slug == $authorcategory) ){
print 'Term exists';
}else{
print 'Term does not exist';
}
?>` I get Term Exist message with this code. Now how do I get the term ID and include it in the dropdown list

Comment: I think I can work it out if someone tell me this-- If term exist get the the ID????

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be mixing up `wp_list_categories` arguments with `wp_dropdown_categories`, so i've removed them from the code that follows, i've also assumed the include argument is suppose to refer to the currently selected item.

For ref:

- [wp_dropdown_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)
- [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories)

**Suggested code:**

```
global $current_user;

get_currentuserinfo();

$authorcategory = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'authorcategory', true );
$user_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $authorcategory, 'blogs');

// Uncomment the two forward slashes before print for debug
// print '<pre>';print_r( $authorcategory );print '</pre>';

if( $user_term ) {
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'show_last_update' => 0,
        'show_count' => 0,
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'selected' => 0,
        'child_of' => $user_term->ID,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'title_li' => __( 'Categories' ),
        'show_option_none' => __('No categories'),
        'taxonomy' => 'blogs'
    );
    wp_dropdown_categories($args); 
}
```

You didn't need either of these two lines..

```
$my_cat_id = get_cat_id($authorcategory);
$my_cat_name = get_cat_name($my_cat_id);
```

You already have a complete object of that term in `$myterm` after you call `get_term_by`.

Hope that helps..

Comment: Now i read that back, i'm not sure the `term_exists` check is even necessary, if `$myterm` has data, then `term_exists` will naturally be true to.

Comment: @t31os Your code seems to be correct but it doesn't show the term nor it is selected . I give a existing term $authorcategory = 'business'; still than no sign

Comment: What I want is only the $authorcategory and if possible block others term from showing

Comment: Please give related tuts and tips links

Comment: Not sure i follow, are you saying you want a dropdown(select) box with only one item in it?

Comment: I didn't follow any guide, i just refer to the documentation and source code in this particular case.  I changed the code a little though, see if it's now working for you(bearing in mind i'm not actually sure what it is you want). Maybe you could chuck together an image of what you're wanting it to appear like? (even something drawn in paint would help)..

Comment: @t31os thanks for your time.  Yes I just want the dropdown(select) box with only one item that is $authorcategory. I am going to hide this dropdown in my posting form. SO by default, every authors get their category selected. Sorry English is my second language

Comment: I am assigning specific category for every authors in my site. I have set the category using the profile meta field 'authorcategory' from dashboard. Than I block access to wp-admin . So author must login and use a custom form to post new post from frontend. So this dropdown list must be included in the form but it has to be hidden (I can do this) . What I exactly need is that the specified category must be selected by default.

Comment: @t31os I want the $myterm->ID to be selected by default I actually don't need the others

Comment: I think I have to use wp list categories and use the include right? I think I am wrong

Comment: Sorry went away for a shower, back now. If you're not providing a switching option and it's going to be hidden, why not just use a hidden input field? eg. `<input type="hidden" name="your-field-name" value="whatevervalue">` Why create a dropdown if it's not going to be used, hidden and unchangable.

Comment: Authors will have sub cats. Actually the parent cat link will become their blog front page. I am also using theme per author plugin

Comment: I am remake it from themepercategory plugin

Comment: You've officially confused me, can you re-examine the original question and see if there's any way you can explain it better? Or alternatively provide more of the code you're using so i can get a better idea of what you're aiming to do.

Comment: I am trying kinda multisite network on Single Wp using CPT

Comment: I want only the $authorcategory to selected as default

Comment: I want only the $authorcategory and the child cats. Yes This is what I want.

Comment: The code i provided should do exactly that, `$myterm` contains an object of the same term retrieved for the user meta call, partly why i'm totally confused about what you want. Like i said, i can't help further without you explaining more about what you're doing or showing me more of the code. Please update the original question with more information(this is my last comment until i have sufficient information to work from).

Comment: Your code works correctly. But I need to hide other terms(category) to the current author. This is like assigning category to author and hiding which are not assigned

Comment: Ok, look, what's inside the user meta field for `authorcategory`, a single slug, or an array of category IDs? Once you tell me that i'll factor in some exclusion code to the sample i provided.. :)

Comment: In the dop list $authorcategory value must be selected by default and show only the child cats of $authorcategory  and other categories should not show up in the list

Comment: So every authors will only see or can select only cats which are assigned to them

Comment: Not quite what i asked, but having said that i think i finally follow you now, i'll update the code in a few moments.

Comment: @ t31os Thanks  a lot for your time and for the code. I have wasted many days but I am also learning more. Thanks once again, Have a nice day

Comment: Sorry but the Last I need something like 'exclude'  => !$myterm->ID, or 'exclude'  => !$authorcategory,

Comment: Updated the code, hope that's what you're after, if not, uncomment the debug line and provide me with the result please(so i can see what the data in your variable looks like).

Comment: it show the cat name "cameroon', I want exclude other categories

Comment: All is well but got to hide other cats

Comment: this is not working 'exclude'  => !$user_term->ID,

Comment: Lose the `!` before `$user_term->ID` .. ;)

Comment: I think i should use the term list......

Comment: Please take this conversation to the chat room - StopPress.

Comment: How to get the term Id of $authorcategory.

Comment: No idea, i don't know what's in your user meta field, based on what you have so far, i'd say it's a category slug. Like i said already though, `$user_term` will hold an object of that term, so `$user_term->term_id` or `$user_term->ID` should hold the applicable ID. As per comment above you, let's move any further discussion into the chatroom, i'll leave a tab open with the chat room open if you're around to jump in for a chat.

Comment: I'll use your code for the time being

Answer (score 2):

This work for me

```
<p>
 <?php 
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $authorcategory = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'authorcategory', true );
  $user_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $authorcategory, 'blogs');
  $mycat = $user_term->slug;
  $cats_array = get_categories(array('child_of=$mycat','taxonomy' => 'blogs'));
 ?>
</p>
<p>
 <strong>Is <?php echo $mycat; ?> your Blog Name? Make it sure before posting </strong>
 <select style=&quot;display:none;&quot; id=&quot;cat&quot; name=&quot;cat&quot; class=&quot;input&quot;>
  <?php foreach ( $cats_array as $category ): ?>
  <?php if ($category->cat_name == $mycat ): ?>
  <option value=&quot;<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>&quot;><?php echo $category->cat_name; ?></option>
  <?php endif; ?>   
  <?php endforeach; ?> 
 </select>
</p>
```